# How do I stream data from TUM RGB-D to ORB-SLAM3 and analyse/record data from that

Tags: ros, slam

I'm very new to the ROS/Slam? can somebody point to any documents/article on the topic of analysing the slam method of running it on several datasets?

i already managed to run the algorithm on the rgb-d and stereo cameras but i dint know how to run it on a dataset

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to see what topics are being published/stored in the dataset. For example, if the dataset uses `/laser` for the lidar pointcloud topic, make sure that it matches with the topics required by the SLAM ROS package. The input topics to SLAM package can easily be found in the documentation of going into the launch file of the ROS packages and seeing what topics are being used.